# Who is right, the statistician or the surgeon?

Tags: experiment-design, clinical-trials

Consider the case described below, from Peacock (1972). This passage seems to imply the young statistician is making a smart, correct statement.

But is he?

[image]

Comment: Your title/question implies that we should be able to determine which "one (and only one) of them is right." The surgeon could be correct in his understanding of the patients prognosis with and without the surgery, but he can't prove that to the satisfaction of the statistician. There are research options other than random assignment to surgery, like finding cases that match the treated population on key pre-treatment covariates.

Comment: @MichaelBishop you can argue that both are right, no problem, as long as you delineate under which assumptions each of them would be right.

Comment: @MichaelBishop in this particular example, I would argue the junior statistician's position is very hard to defend, considering the nature of the surgery.

Comment: Is this a question for some subject?

Comment: @Glen_b it's theoretical, the paragraph seems to imply the surgeon is wrong, but that seems debatable from a statistical decision theory perspective.

Comment: At least, should use the historical control to prove that the surgery is useful. The conclusion without comparison is terrible.

Comment: Nonsense, each patient is his own control.

Answer (score 3):

As the statistician did not make any statements, he cannot be wrong. He just asked two questions: 1) Did you have controls? and 2) Which half?

The surgeon is clearly wrong, unless a) Every patient he treated survived and b) No patient who was not treated would survive (or, of course, vice versa).

Both the surgeon and the statistician are making good points.

Comment: Thanks, but your conditions seem too stringent. What if a) most treated patients survided and b) most untreated patients died ? I would claim the statistician can be wrong indeed, since he is suggesting that we cannot know or claim anything without doing a RCT.

Comment: @statslearner2 "Controls" ≠ "randomization", and the statistician in the quoted story did not propose or imply randomization, but explicitly named and agreed with a definition of controls.

Comment: The other possibility is that the "audience" is being held 6 months post op. Those with vascular reconstruction live 1 year, and those without live longer.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like that story about one of the sons in the fourth generation of the Pearson family, the one that became a paramedic. He used to not help half of his patients with a cardiac arrest in order to test whether helping or not helping was significantly helpful in order to get the heart beating again.

A grand child of Joan Fisher and Joerge Box is currently doing a project for the final exam as air traffic controller. He is testing on half the pilot whether they will fly better and crash less often if he is not speaking to them.

Do you think they are right to do so?

Comment: There are many variations of this joke, like e.g. no double-blind testing has ever been performed for the effectiveness of parachutes so how can we know they are any useful; etc.

Comment: @Amoeba See Yeh *et al.*, "Parachute use to prevent death and major trauma when jumping from aricraft: randomized controlled trial," BMJ 2018;363:k5094
http://dx.doi.org/10.1136/bmj.k5094 (published one week after your comment).

Comment: ah, I see, it is a joke. I thought statslearner was serious and for that reason, I made it more extreme to show how the argument is not right (The solution being like: not all knowledge needs to come from a test, but it can also be deduced from previous knowledge).

Answer (score 1):

The statistician sounds like a frequentist, and he's correct if we view things in terms of measures of evidence. In particular, at this point we have no direct evidence in regards to the effectiveness of the surgeon's effectiveness.

Maybe surprising to most statisticians, the surgeon is taking more of a Bayesian perspective. That is, because of his advanced knowledge of medicine, he is very strongly convinced that his procedures are helping his patients. He's human, so he must realize that he does know *exactly* how effective his treatments are, but he also is so confident that it's positive that the long-term benefit is better for him to treat every patient than it is to collect controls, who will with very high probability be worse off than if they were treated only to collect data that confirms what he already knows. So while collecting data on controls may be informative, it is dangerous to the controls and not likely to make any differences in future decisions. Therefore, it is quite logical for him to not use controls.

Who's correct? Well, the statistician is certainly correct that we don't have any data that demonstrates that the surgeon's methods are effective.

But the lack of evidence doesn't mean the surgeon is wrong! **Assuming the surgeon is not over-confident**, the surgeon is also correct that collecting data on controls is not the ethical thing to do. What it all comes down to is: do you trust the surgeon's confidence?

Comment: Are you offering us a choice between science-by-evidence and science-by-authority? ;-)

Comment: @whuber: how about "science-by-personal-trust"? But moreover, it's not *just* a question of science.

Answer (score 0):

The surgeon is right.

The people who suffered or died because they did not get this operation serve as a control group. It would be better to formalize this and quantify the improved performance (e.g. 70% mortality rate vs 10%), but we do have a group to which we can compare.

Now...if the surgeon is claiming that his treatment saved lives, yet the patients tended to do just fine without the procedure, then the success of the treatment is not so remarkable. However, quite the opposite is implied.

The "which half" line is wrong. Nothing suggests that the surgeon's procedure causes death. Perhaps it doesn't help compared to a control group, but it certainly sounds like most patients survive. Operating on a patient certainly doesn't suggest that they are doomed to die in the OR.

Comment: Well, all the patients will die....eventually.

Comment: "The people who suffered or died because they did not get this operation serve as a control group". I know this more of a mental exercise, but in general, this is a very flawed analysis. Without question, subjects who try to get the operation are quite different from subjects who did not and generally will greatly bias the estimated effects. A classical example of this type of mistake is the infamous [HRT study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Million_Women_Study).